# What's used as the Ukrainian for troika?

Tags: переклад, from-russian

What's used as the Ukrainian for the English word "troika", when referring to the horse drawn carriage, as opposed to the travel card or as a metaphorical gang of three?

Wiktionary says it's трі́йка, but a Ukrainian speaker [says](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/88416/is-troika-riding-available-as-a-tourist-experience-in-ukraine/88429#comment210012_88429) that "brichka" is used.

Wiktionary has an entry for the English word britchka, but no translation information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Brychka](http://sum.in.ua/s/brychka) is [more general class](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0) of transport [vehicle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phaeton_body). Actually it is a [wagon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wagon) which may be carried by technicaly unimited number of horses :)

Troika ([*трійка*](http://sum.in.ua/s/trijka)) is a brychka drawn by *three* horses:

> Троє коней, запряжених поряд в один [екіпаж](http://sum.in.ua/s/ekipazh). //  [Екіпаж](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/equipage) із запряженими в нього трьома кіньми; тройка.

Comment: Which word is more frequently used?

Comment: I can't tell you for sure. People does not talk about troika's and brychkas often. But as for me trijka has quite a colonial scent of old-russian-emperial past and brychka has a bit of flavour of bourgeoisie utopia. So the intent of speaker may influence choise of the word

Comment: Is either "old-russian-[imperial] past" or "bourgeoisie utopia" likely to offend Ukrainians?

Comment: I don't think these words may offend anyone. Brychkas with one or two horses used to be more common in our lands. Having brychka with three horses may be considered as showing-off rather than for reasons of usefulness :) But it's my very subjective thought

Comment: I haven't seen anyone offended by trijka usage, but I suppose people who don't like this word do exist. On the other hand it almost impossible to imagine one calling someone's car trijka in given sense. But calling someone's car brychka ironically implies it hardly able to move without  external assistance. But `віз` (wagon) is quite neutral alias for a car

Comment: @AndrewGrimm, in addition to what Chizh said, I'd prefer to say "brychka" just because it's more narrow sense. "Triyka" just means "three (as noun)" and it can mean anything: a school mark, a sort of beer, an [NKVD commission](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NKVD_troika), a playing card, a digit itself. While "brychka" is a specific kind of vehicle (although not necessarily with exactly three horses).

Answer (score 7):

Трійка means that three horses are used, while they may "drive" different types of carriage, including sleigh.

> [ТРІЙКА](http://sum.in.ua/s/trijka) Троє коней, запряжених поряд в один екіпаж.

Бричка is a type of carriage, while it can be drawn by different number of horses.

> [БРИ́ЧКА](http://sum.in.ua/s/brychka), и, жін. Легкий візок для їзди, іноді з відкидним верхом.

Answer (score 5):

There is another option, though outdated

> **ТРОЯН**
>   Троє (коней). *На друге літо — обзавівся* [Максим] *трояном коней* (Панас Мирний, I, 1949, 238); *Його примчав на мальованій
>   таращанській бричці троян вороних коней* (Михайло Стельмах, I, 1962,
>   319).

- [SUM](http://slovnyk.sum.in.ua/s/trojan)
- [r2u](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on)